# Android customizing style inheritance

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, fonts, themes

I have an app with a customizable theme. The user can currently switch between 3 themes, which each change the background color, font color and font for the main display area, but not buttons or other widgets. Since there isn't a really good way to specify custom fonts in a theme, my application code is switching the typeface (using `Typeface.CreateFromAsset` and `TextView.Typeface`) in parallel with resetting the theme (using `SetTheme`). (I believe the non-Xamarin version of these are `Typeface.createFromAsset`, `TextView.setTypeface` and `setTheme`, BTW.) But I noticed that the fancy font looked smaller compared to the others, so whenever I use that theme I want the font to be bigger. So I created the following theme that inherits from my main theme:

```
<style name="Theme.StoryvoqueFancy" parent="@style/Theme.StoryvoqueLight">
   <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
   <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">5sp</item>
   <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The textSize attribute accomplishes what I want it to with the main text, making it larger. What I can't figure out is how to arrange my attributes or styles such that it doesn't affect other text. Notice in my screenshots below that the button text is also getting larger when I use this theme.

### Default theme

[image: Screenshot with default font]

### Fancy Theme

[image: Screenshot with fancy font]

Ideally, I think I want a theme to be able to specify attributes that will only apply to the main view with something like:

```
<item name="mainViewTextSize">18sp</item>
```

And then I would somehow reference mainViewTextSize from my TextView. Or I'd like to use:

```
<item name="textSizeTertiary">18sp</item>
```

because textColorTertiary seems to affect the text in the main view, but not the buttons. But no such attribute exists.

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I'm approaching this from the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

A file `attrs.xml` can be added to the `Resources\values\` directory with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <attr name="mainViewTextSize" format="dimension"/>
</resources>
```

to define a custom attribute name.

This attribute can be referenced in the themes.xml file like this:

```
<style name="Theme.StoryvoqueFancy" parent="@style/Theme.StoryvoqueLight">
   <item name="mainViewTextSize">18sp</item>
   <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Then the axml layout file can reference it like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:textSize="?mainViewTextSize" />
```

However, it appears necessary, then to define mainViewTextSize in every theme, otherwise an error will be encountered:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class  occurred

It also appears important to avoid recursion (don't default the value of `mainViewTextSize` to `android:textSize`) otherwise the same error will be encountered.

## Update

After taking the other answer into account, I have arrived at the following themes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="TextAppearance.Storyvoque.MainView" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault" />
   <style name="Theme.StoryvoqueLight" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:actionBarSize">32dip</item>
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.StoryvoqueLight.ActionBar</item>
      <item name="mainViewStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Storyvoque.MainView</item>
   </style>
   <style name="Theme.StoryvoqueLight.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
      <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.StoryvoqueLight.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
   </style>
   <style name="Theme.StoryvoqueLight.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.ActionBar.Solid">
      <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
   </style>
   <style name="Theme.StoryvoqueRetro" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
      <item name="android:actionBarSize">32dip</item>
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.StoryvoqueLight.ActionBar</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
      <item name="mainViewStyle">@style/TextAppearance.Storyvoque.Retro</item>
   </style>
   <style name="TextAppearance.Storyvoque.Retro" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault">
      <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
   </style>
   <style name="Theme.StoryvoqueFancy" parent="@style/Theme.StoryvoqueLight">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/papyrus</item>
      <item name="mainViewStyle">@style/Theme.StoryvoqueFancy.Text</item>
      <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">8dp</item>
   </style>
   <style name="Theme.StoryvoqueFancy.Text" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Storyvoque.MainView">
      <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

My axml file contains this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"            
    android:textAppearance="?mainViewStyle"
```

My attrs.xml file contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <attr name="mainViewStyle" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

I'm still not sure if this is ideal, but it seems slightly better-designed that my earlier solution, and seems good enough to me in the absence of any further suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Given that **themes are global** and **styles are local**, you would want to be creating a *specific style* that is applied to the `View` level instead of globally.

With that said you should define a `TextAppearance` that your **style** will inherit and ultimately be applied to your `View`. If you need any customization on the **style**, you can create [**custom style attributes**](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr).

Comment: I am allowing the user to select alternate global styles which *should* affect the global appearance. But when they select the fancy style, I need to refine what happens on one particular view because I only want the size and line spacing to be applied to one view when this style is active. It's not clear to me whether your answer addresses that -- I may need more detail if so.

Comment: I kind of figured out what you were suggesting, I think, and added it to my answer. I'm a little unsure about the placement of lineSpacingExtra. But everything seems to look pretty much how I wanted. I'm open to refinements if I missed part of your point, though.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was suggesting.